# How can I let anonymous users view user profiles by role?

Tags: users

I have 2 different roles like A and B.

I want anonymous users (everyone) can view user profiles from A role but can't view user profiles from B role.

In summary, A role profiles is open for everyone but B is not.

Access user profiles permission or [View profiles permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_profiles_perms) module is not enough for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [hook_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7) function to handle the permission. At first you need to copy the original function as below in the template.php

```
function hook_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    if (user_access('create blog content', $account)) {
        $account->content['summary']['blog'] = array(
        '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
        '#title' => t('Blog'),
        '#markup' => l(t('View recent blog entries'), "blog/$account->uid",  array('attributes' => array('title' => t("Read !username's latest blog entries.", array('!username' => format_username($account)))))),
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('blog')),
);
      }
 }
```

Then check the current user role and the role of the user that is being visited. current user role is get by this:

```
global $user;
$role = $user->role;
```

the role of the profile is saved in the `$account` variable. Check to see what exactly its syntax is using `devel` module (I forgot the code syntax), If it was not there, you can get the owner of the profile `id`, use `user_load(id)` function to load the user then get its role. 
After getting the roles, you should perform the condition at the first line of the hook function.

Comment: It was a bit hard way for me but works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to achieve this. Under **Page Settings** change Access to Role & select **Anonymous users** from the list. Check exported view shown below:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'user_profiles';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'users';
$view->human_name = 'User Profiles';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'User Profiles';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'role';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['role'] = array(
  1 => '1',
);
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
/* Field: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['uid']['link_to_user'] = FALSE;
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['path'] = 'user-profile/[uid]';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_user'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: User: Created date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: User: Active */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: User: Roles */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['id'] = 'rid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['table'] = 'users_roles';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['field'] = 'rid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['rid']['value'] = array(
  5 => '5',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'user-profiles';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['pager'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: User: Rendered User */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['id'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['table'] = 'views_entity_user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['field'] = 'rendered_entity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['link_to_entity'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['display'] = 'view';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['view_mode'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered_entity']['bypass_access'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['arguments'] = FALSE;
/* Contextual filter: User: Uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_type'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['default_argument_options']['user'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['uid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'user-profile/%';
```

In my case, I wanted to list user of role **field executive**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that is not what I am looking for. There must be a cleaner solution to limit anonymous users view site user profiles by role.